# MAMP PRO 4.1.1 SSL - Your connection is not private

Tags: ssl, mamp, mamp-pro

I've been using MAMP with SSL's for a while with no issue but upgrading to 4.1.1 has broken them. Local sites that worked fine beofre the upghrade are now showing 'Your connection is not private'.

My method has always been:
- Create local site
- enable and create SSL on the SSL tab in MAMP PRO
- drag the .crt file into Keychain and tell it to always trust

I beielve this to be a bug with the latest version of Mamp pro. Is anyone having the same issue or if its working for you what were your steps to use SSL locally on 4.1.1. Thanks!
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Chrome 58 update. I contacted Mamp support:-

> Hi, Chrome just updated to v58 and now all my MAMP self-signed
>   certificates apparently need to use subjectAltName instead of Common
>   Name.
>
> I'm assuming MAMP is using
>   Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf to config the certs.
>
> Is this something that will be patched in future versions, as I like
>   the ease with which I can add certificates in MAMP? (or maybe it's not
>   a MAMP issue at all)
>
> https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Fixing-Chrome-missing_subjectAltName-selfsigned-cert-openssl/

They said:

> We are looking into this. We will have a new version of MAMP PRO
>   available in several weeks. I can't guarantee the fix will be in this
>   version. The developers are aware there is an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response!

Comment: That fixed it! - for anyone else looking for Chome 57 to fix this: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php